# Visual Studio 2022 not loading Android project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, ide

I am attempting to open a solution with 9 projects, inside a workspace on TFS, via VS 2022. I have tried using both VS 2022 Community 17.5.0 and VS 2022 Professional LTSC 17.4. Neither have that issue initially, but after some use, the problem manifests.

The solution has a Xamarin.Forms project targeting .net standard 2.0, and has an Android project upon which the solution load hangs. I've left this for many hours, but it seems to make no progress, staying in this state indefinitely:

[image: The loading windows stays in this state indefinitely]

Upon clicking on the VS taskbar I get the Windows Notification: "Visual Studio is busy - We'll automatically report this delay to Microsoft based on your Visual Studio Experience Improvement Program settings."

I can only manage to temporarily solve this issue by reinstalling VS. Repairing via the VS installer does not solve it. Neither does restarting VS or my laptop. Even reinstalling as a solution I am not too confident about due to the intermittentness of the issue. And that is not addressing the root cause.

Comment: Have you checked the VS logs?

Comment: I've checked the VS logs under %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\, but no new logs are written upon experiencing this issue. The only message on VS UI is: "Loading project file [path to Android project]/[Android.project.name].csproj"

Comment: The only indication of an error I could file so far, was in the Windows Event Viewer: "The program devenv.exe version 17.5.33414.496 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel." devenv.exe Being the VS .exe file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Goto Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->General and remove the tick at "Allow parallel project initialization"

After disabling the parallel initialization of projects I could load the
solution successfully multiple times. Enabling this feature brings back the problem.

Addendum: This is NOT fixed in 17.5.2

Addendum 2: Still under investigation - NOT fixed in 17.5.3

Addendum 3: Microsoft has closed this as Fixed in 17.6 Preview 3

(see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-V175-hangs-when-loading-an-Andro/10292905?q=VS2022+17.5+hangs+when+loading+solution+with+Android+or+iOS+project)

Addendum 4: Installed the Released Version of 17.6 today. Loading worked a few times, than hung again as before. Other reported this as well (see developer community link above).

Addendum 5: This seems to be fixed in 17.7.0 Preview 6.0
I was able to load the solution several times without a problem.

**Addendum 6: This is fixed in 17.7**

[image]

Comment: Everything come back alive after doing this. Hope it's a long term solution for my solution. I need to always delete .vs to open.

Answer (score 4):

For now, the easiest fix is to delete your hidden .vs folder for the solution.  You then should be able to open the solution as normal.

Comment: When deleting such 'system' folders, it is always a good idea to make a backup/copy of that folder, first - just in case anything unexpected happens and data or settings are lost.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem; the only way to load the remaining projects was to remove the project from source control (Azure Dev ops). It was the only thing I could find that enables me to keep working.

Comment: What steps do you follow to remove the project from source control?

Comment: I usually do like this

in visual studio, go to file --> Source Control --> Advanced --> change Source Control

a new window will appear and do Unbind.

But the cause of the problem in my opinion, I think it's the last visual studio update that messed something up.

Answer (score 1):

In April 2023 the solution is delete the folder .vs from you solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your SDK is correctly set up. Also, check all versions you have downloaded and installed correctly.